# How to get Total record count of individual views from all_views

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

How to get Total record count of individual views from all_views.
Please find below code for reference..

```
Declare
view_name     VARCHAR2(200);
v_str          VARCHAR2 (1000);
v_output     VARCHAR2(4000);

CURSOR tbl IS
     SELECT view_name 
     FROM all_views
     WHERE OWNER = SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA')
     ORDER BY 1 ;
BEGIN
OPEN tbl ;
     LOOP
     FETCH tbl INTO view_name;
     EXIT WHEN tbl%NOTFOUND;
          v_str := 'Select '''|| view_name ||'     '' || count (*) from ' || view_name ;
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_str INTO v_output;

          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_output);
     END LOOP;
CLOSE tbl;
END;
```

**current output :**

```
V_DSP_BUSINESS_DATE            10
V_DSP_DEPARTMENT               20
V_DSP_EMPLOYEE_DEACTIVATED     50
V_DSP_EMPLOYEE_GED             80
```

**Expected output :**

```
sum up the record count of all individual views

i.e 160
```

Kindly help.

Comment: can you make your expected output more clear i.e. you want only 160 without view name or 160 against every view name.

Comment: Add the count inside the loop and put the dbms_output after the end loop. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply modify the `LOOP` to sum up for each time it fetches the `COUNT`.

```
LOOP
FETCH tbl INTO view_name;
EXIT WHEN tbl%NOTFOUND;
     v_str := 'Select count (*) from ' || view_name ;
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_str INTO v_cnt;
     v_cnt_tot := v_cnt_tot + v_cnt;


END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cnt_tot);
```

Make sure you declare the `v_cnt` and `v_cnt_tot` variables.

If you really want to do it in `LOOP` i.e. `row-by-row`, then use a simple **CURSOR FOR LOOP** rather than declaring a `CURSOR`.

Something like,

```
FOR i IN SELECT view_name 
     FROM all_views
     WHERE OWNER = SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA')
LOOP
...
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark it as answered if it has solved your problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

thank you so much for your help...:) 
It worked.

Please find below final code

```
Declare
view_name     VARCHAR2(200);
v_str          VARCHAR2 (1000);
v_cnt     VARCHAR2(4000);
v_cnt_tot     VARCHAR2(4000);

CURSOR tbl IS
     SELECT view_name 
     FROM all_views
     WHERE OWNER = SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA')
     ORDER BY 1 ;

BEGIN
 v_cnt_tot := 0;
OPEN tbl ;
     LOOP
     FETCH tbl INTO view_name;
     EXIT WHEN tbl%NOTFOUND;
          v_str := 'Select  count (*) as count from ' || view_name ;
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_str INTO v_cnt;
          v_cnt_tot := v_cnt_tot + v_cnt;


     END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cnt_tot);
CLOSE tbl;
END;
```

Comment: If you are using Oracle SQL Developer, put this at the top of your script:

set serveroutput on;

Otherwise you will get a generic PL\SQL script ran successfully output.